# Cannot load such file -- unicorn/version (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, unicorn

Attempting to switch from WEBrick to Unicorn, I've got the Unicorn gem v 4.8.1 installed on my machine [via "gem install unicorn"] and it's also located in my Gemfile ["gem "unicorn", "~> 4.8.1"], for which I've successfully run bundle install.

However, when starting the server locally via "rails s" (worked fine pre-Unicorn), I get the following error:

```
...../vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.1/lib/unicorn/const.rb:44:in `require': cannot load such file -- unicorn/version (LoadError)
    from /Users/johndoe/Sites/my_app/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.1/lib/unicorn/const.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/johndoe/Sites/my_app/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.1/lib/unicorn.rb:108:in `require'
    from /Users/johndoe/Sites/my_app/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.1/lib/unicorn.rb:108:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/johndoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /Users/johndoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/johndoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /Users/johndoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /Users/johndoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /Users/johndoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/johndoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/johndoe/Sites/my_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/johndoe/Sites/my_app/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Users/johndoe/Sites/my_app/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/johndoe/Sites/my_app/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/johndoe/Sites/my_app/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm thinking this may be due to using RVM? When I type 'which gem "unicorn"' I get:

```
/Users/johndoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/gem
/Users/johndoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/unicorn
```

Also for reference, my $PATH: `/Users/johndoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/gem:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/Users/joh‌​ndoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/Users/johndoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@globa‌​l/bin:/Users/johndoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/Users/johndoe/.rvm/bin:/usr‌​/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin`

"bundle show unicorn" gives: /Users/johndoe/Sites/my_app/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.1

The application successfully deploys to Heroku, so I believe this issue is isolated to my machine (rather than being an issue with the application). Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: update the post, with the output

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ which output?

Comment: and provide output of `bundle show unicorn`, and `ls $(bundle show unicorn)/lib/unicorn/version`

Comment: that output which you've provided as a comment

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I have updated the post - there is no ls $(bundle show unicorn)/lib/unicorn/version directory - although there is a ls $(bundle show unicorn)/lib/unicorn/ directory

Comment: sorry of course `ls $(bundle show unicorn)/lib/unicorn/`. version is the file although =)

Comment: Does `bundle exec rails s` give the same error?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ hmm - no "version" file, but here is the ls of the .../lib/unicorn directory: app   const.rb  http_server.rb  preread_input.rb ssl_configurator.rb tee_input.rb  worker.rb
cgi_wrapper.rb  http_request.rb  launcher.rb  socket_helper.rb ssl_server.rb  tmpio.rb
configurator.rb  http_response.rb oob_gc.rb  ssl_client.rb  stream_input.rb  util.rb

Comment: @berkes - yes, same error. also tried "bundle exec unicorn -p 3000 -c ./config/unicorn.rb" but same output

Comment: Indeed the unicorn gem has no version.rb,  show line `script/rails:6:in `require'`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ scripts/rails:6 = require 'rails/commands'. Also, the line causing the error (top line of the dump) is "require 'unicorn/version'"

Comment: remove `require 'unicorn/version'`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ that produces a new error - "/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.1/lib/unicorn/http_request.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- unicorn_http (LoadError)"

Comment: I don't think the issue is in the unicorn library itself, but rather in my installation of the gem.

Comment: ` don't think the issue is in the unicorn library itself, ` probably it depends on how did you install it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46664/discussion-between---and-aaron-marks)

Comment: If you fix the installation, you will get the properly run unicorn, because I see you have many improper require calls to the unicorn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seemed to fix the problem by uninstalling the gem via "sudo bundle exec gem uninstall unicorn", then reinstalling it via standard "sudo bundle install"

Still not sure exactly why the issue occurred, but that fix did seem to work.

Comment: Used this twice in one day. Since the command asked me to uninstall two different versions, they were conflicting in some manner.

Answer (score 0):

Can you used this..

```
$ rails server unicorn
```

or

```
bundle exec unicorn -p 3000
```

Answer (score -1):

Still not sure what caused this problem.

I solved this simply by reinstalling the unicorn gem.
gem uninstall unicorn
bundle install
bundle update